# Adding JButton in a column in JTable (JAVA)

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable, jbutton

I am currently reading an excel sheet (**.xls**) and placing it in a `JTable`. The excel sheet consists of 3 columns. I am successfully able to read it. However, when reading the excel sheet, I want to add an extra fourth column in the `JTable` that includes `JButtons` (One button for each row). When `JButton` is clicked in a row, I want to take the content of the third column and perform some action.
I am currently using the code from [here](http://niravjavadeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/01/import-excel-data-into-jtable.html).

What is the best way to add `JButtons` in a `JTable` column?

Comment: This is just my opinion, but buttons in tables is an out date mode of interaction, why not allow the user to select one or more rows and then use an external button to perform the action(s) on the selected rows?

Comment: The problem is that the task requires using buttons in JTable.

Comment: Take a look at [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/), you'll also want to take a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can add your button this way.

```
class MyRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    JButton button = new JButton();

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {

        button.setText(value.toString());
        return button;
    }
```

and to add action listener do this

```
class mybutttoneditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor,
            ActionListener {

        JTable table;
        JButton button = new JButton();



        public mybutttoneditor(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;

             button.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
             button.setForeground(Color.blue);
             button.addActionListener(this);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          final int row = table.getEditingRow();
        String column3data=table.getValueAt(row, 2);
        //do what you want with the data here 
        //hopefully this helps and if so accept the answer
        }
        //other abstract methods are here
        }
}

    DefaultTableModel md=(DefaultTableModel)mytable.getModel();

    //do this while reading your excel sheet

    Object row[]={"dataone","datatwo","data3","Open Button"};
    md.addRow(row);
    TableColumnModel colModel = mytable.getColumnModel();
    colModel.getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new MyRenderer());
   colModel.getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new mybutttoneditor(mytable));
```

Comment: You can convert your excell sheet into CSV and read it directly without using excel lib

Comment: Now, how does the OP respond to events from the button?

Comment: @MadProgrammer have you managed to display the button in the table first? that is the first step.

Comment: Not not original poster, but this answers only have the question (IMHO, this is just a bad idea)

Comment: for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) { Vector d = new Vector();             for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) {                                             Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);                                 d.add(cell.getContents()); }                                                           d.add("\n"); data.add(d); } } catch (BiffException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }

If I am using this code to add the data?? how can I manage to use your code?? (hopefully the code is clear) @NemugaM

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class extending JButton. Then add property to that class.(field with getter and setter) when you adding data to the table, add JButton instance for each row using your custom JButton class and set value in the third column using setter method. So you can use that value in processing in the click event. Hope it helps :)